# Best way to handle flask POST unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

I have the following code, that accepts a POST request and processes it.

*index.py*

```
@app.route('/route', methods=['POST'])
def route_post():
    try:
        data = request.get_data()
        j = json.loads(data)
    except Exception as e:
    ...
```

Basically, I want access to request.get_data() so I can change the value. I'm invoking the test as shown below, which is dead simple.

*route_test.py:*

```
def test_route():
    assert(("Bad Request\r\n", 400) == route_post())
```

But doesn't allow me to set the value of request.get_data(). How can I do this?

Comment: you want access to request.get_data() in the unit test?

Comment: There's no straight forward way to set the POST data (body), which is retrieved by request.get_data(). That's the one answer suggests using mocks/patch to patch that method and set the value.

Comment: If you stuff data to the body of the request and make a normal http post you are making this an integration test. You shouldn't care where or how get_data finds the data at runtime, only how that data will look like so you can test your function in isolation.

Answer (score 2):

Use the test client to post whatever data you need to the route.  If `data` is a string or bytes, Werkzeug sends the data directly, as bytes.

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder=None)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def index():
    return request.get_data()

c = app.test_client()
r = c.post('/', data='Hello, World!')
print(r.data)  # b'Hello, World!'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can patch method get_data of the request object with a mock object that returns what you tell it to return. Something along the lines of:

```
from mock import patch

@patch('flask.Request.get_data')
def test_route_post(self, get_deta_mock):
    get_deta_mock.return_value = '{"foo": "bar"}'
    result = route_post()
    assert result['foo'] == 'bar'
```